# Efficiently computing the properties of a Chebyshev series

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, numerical-analysis

Suppose we have some function $f(x)$ defined as a Chebyshev series up to order $M$:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{M} c_n T_n(x). $$

For a given coefficients vector $\mathbf{c}$, and $x \in [-1,1]$ I'm looking to determine the following:

- Is $f(x) > 0$ everywhere?
- The *maximum* value of the gradient $f'(x)$
- The number of stationary points i.e. where $f'(x) = 0$

These properties are of course not difficult to determine, but computational efficiency is an important factor for me in this case.

I'd love any suggestions of efficient ways to answer these qustions starting only from the coefficients, and no prior calculation of $f(x)$ values.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: (1) *2* and *3* are solved by reducing them to eigenvalue problems of size $M\times M$: chebfun is an example of an existing package than does this. (2) I think *1* follows from *3* because the minimum of $f$ will be at $f'=0$ or an endpoint. (3) Since $f'$ can be straightforwardly represented as its own Chebyshev series, the distinction between $f$ and $f'$ might be unnecessary, e.g., *2* asks for roots of $f''$, so I think the only question here is "given Chebyshev series, find its roots", which is solved by chebfun and similar projects using a colleague matrix, see their published papers.

Comment: @Kirill Excellent info, thanks. I'll go check out chebfun now.